# MIPS - Forwarding in static multiple-issue

Tags: mips, pipeline, cpu-architecture

On a static two-issue pipeline for MIPS, can I use the forwarding paths with two instructions running in the same clock cycle?

For example:

`1. add $t0, $t0, $t1
 2. sw  $t0, 0($t2)`

Can I execute these two instructions on the same clock cycle? 
The `sw` could use the resulting value of the `add` when it is going to execute the MEM stage.

Is that correct?

Comment: If you can get the correct data at the right time and without inserting any bubbles (though this would only affect the performance) then I don't see any problems in implementing that forwarding path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you consider a typical 5 stage pipeline (IF, ID, EX, MEM, WB), the output of the `ADD` will be available at `EX -> MEM` interface. For the `MEM` stage of the `SW` instruction, it needs the memory address, which is `0 + ($t2)` and the data which is supposed to be in `$t0`. However `$t0` has not been updated yet, as the pipeline has not reached `WB` stage. However the value which is supposed to be written to `$t0` is available at `EX->MEM` stage. Therefore, you can use forwarding in this scenario to execute `SW` instruction without waiting for `ADD` to complete.